# Adjusting the current Style of a Control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, wpf-style

Let's say we have a `ListView`. Somewhere in our `Resources` there is a `Style` for `ListView`'s which is being applied automatically. That `Style` sets the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            ...
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ListView x:Name="SpecialListView">
    ...
</ListView>
```

Now I want to change the `ItemContainerStyle` of `SpecialListView`. However I don't want to completely replace it. Instead I just want to set one property (let's say `Background`).

The only solution I can come up with is naming the `Style` used for `ItemContainerStyle` in `Resources` and create a new one based on it. I don't want to do that, though. We might not know which `Style` is applied or might not be able to set the name for the sub-`Style`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you checked [Style.BasedOn Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Comment: Which part of your code decides which style detail (backgound) is used? You need to add those information. If you want to reuse Style, the only option left are triggers.

Comment: @tagaPdyk The ItemContainerStyle in the Resources sets the background (and a lot of other stuff). How would I use Triggers to reuse a Style?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, this may be a little simplified. But shows the main idea

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
            Tb1
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox>Tb2</TextBox>
        <TextBox>Tb3</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to name the sub-Style used in Resources. So I cannot reference it in the BasedOn syntax.

Comment: I'm an idiot for not reading your answer carefully. It actually does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can distinguish the specific case you may use converter.

In the generic style for the specific property bind to specific converter.
The default logic of the converter returns the generic style value and in the specific case the other value.

Comment: If you have more than one property that you want to change, you can use trigger that will be active if the converter return true. In the trigger you can set all the properties that you want to change

Comment: How would the Converter know on which object he i used on? Besides that, I don't want to change the global style.
How would I use Triggers without setting the Style?

Comment: You can use my solution only if you can distinguish the different cases in the converter, ex: by checking the ViewModel or something similar. Also my solution is based on the fact that you modify the global style with all the logic. It's ugly I'm agree but in some cases it enables you to write the style once